# Displaying Javascript Content In HTML Or Php Variable

Tags: php, html, ajax, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have javascript that gets the Facebook name of a user when they login on my file indir.php. However, I cannot get that name javascript variable to transform into a php variable or a `<input type="hidden" name="name" value="" />`. Currently, I can get the name using:

```
<script>
...facebook stuff...
function login() {
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block";
    var mos = response.name;
    document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = mos;
  }
}
...
</script>
```

And then display the name using:

```
<div id="login" style ="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: To "transform" it you'll have to send it to PHP via AJAX.

Comment: How would I do that? I am not familiar with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  should  let  you get the name in the field

First  Add an id  to the  input  field

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="fb_name" value="" />
```

Then

```
<script>
...facebook stuff...
function login() {
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block";
    var mos = response.name;
    document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = mos;
   //Enter the value in  field
    var field= document.getElementById("fb_name");
    field.value = mos;
}
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send it to php in a POST-request using AJAX:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var content = "c=" + mos;

xhr.open("POST", "serverscript.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(content);
```

Receive at server side using something like

```
<?php    

if (isset($_POST['c'])) {
    $data = htmlspecialchars($_POST['c'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
}

?>
```

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. This is better as a comment.

Comment: @Jay. If I could I would!

Comment: I know @player - you just need to do a couple of more edits to earn the rep needed to post comments. Folks are likely to downvote this and make you lose points.

Comment: @Jay. Ok, thanks for the heads-up, but he will find the answer he needs in the link I posted, hence my post answers his question?

Comment: No, if you put the code needed (don't copy) to answer his question then it would be an answer. A link to another answer is typically considered a *duplicate* answer and is a reason to close a question.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that the opening brackets on the FB.api call are not closed see snippet below.
If this is this done then the javascript function will update the div with the value of response.name.

It would only need to be a php variable if you are doing something with the information server side. You could then send it using AJAX if needed.

```
function login(){ 
  FB.api('/me', function(response) { 
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block"; 
    var mos = response.name; 
    document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = mos; 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this something like this:

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
var name = 'Luis';
var variablejs = 'Your javascript value: ' + name ;
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$variablephp = "<script> document.write(variablejs) </script>";
echo "variablephp = $variablephp";
?>
```